# Can I restrict specific columns/cells from being selectable by the CellSelectionModel plugin?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I need to disable cell selection for the first two columns of a grid.

Does slickgrid/CellSelectionModel support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set 'selectable:false' on a column definition.